# Recursive array analysis (math program)

Tags: php, arrays, math, recursion, trigonometry

I'm making a PHP trigonometry tool using PHP that can analyze how best to solve a given problem.

For instance, I know angle A and sides b and c, and I need the computer to calculate which formulas to use in which order to make the best mathematical solution to finding an unknown value.

Right now, I have created an array with numerous options on how to find the unknown value:

[Image of array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DgZ0i.png)

The array is made like this:`[formula: xxx]` is a suggestion on what formula to use to find a previous value.
`[target: xxx]` is the name of the value we're looking for in order to satisfy the need of the previous formula.

There might be more than one target attached to a formula, because a formula might need more than one information in order to be complete.

At the end of each path there is an array showing a mathematical function which can be solved with the information we have, and if you track backwards from there you have enough information to solve the task which was initially given (which was angle B (cannot be seen on the image, but it is))

So, out of all of these solution options I need to find the shortest solution, the solution which requires the fewest steps.

Keep in mind that a formula might have two unknown variables, which means that we need to calculate the total sum of the shortest path and end up with the an array containing the optimal path.

---

Bonus question: I'm aware that this only solves the problem using the information provided by the user, maybe at some point along the way we find a variable, which is needed at some other point. Maybe if a function needs two variables, it is faster to find A before B before A calculates a "target" which might be needed in B.

I would really like to have a solution for the first part, but I will need to solve the "bonus question" later on.

Comment: This is a really abstract problem so showing a PHP array is really misleading. Finding the shortest solution usually implies some sort of AI search algorithm like A*.

Comment: I'd look into trees (graphs). Generate the solution space as a tree, then finding the correct solution should be just a matter of walking down the tree. Can't give you a good book on this subject from the top of my head though. I think a search for "solution space enumeration" should bring up a number of good starting points.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search